# Reading and writing to MySQL from within a customised php function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a function that, when called, selects values out of the DB, adds them up and then inserts the total back into the DB again. Here is what I have so far:

```
function doAddup01() {
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `number1`, `number2`, `number3` FROM $database.tablename WHERE `id` = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $caseID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result01 = $stmt->fetchAll();

        // Add up all the relevant fields
        $tot = $result01[0]['number1'] + $result01[0]['number2'] + $result01[0]['number3'];
        // Write the totalled value to the DB

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.tablename SET `totalVal` = :data WHERE `id` = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':data', $tot, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $caseID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    // Echo out the tallied result
    $report_name['total'] = num($tot);
    echo json_encode($report_name);
}
```

The num function simply formats numerals into comma separated increments like 1000 becomes 1,000.

I am getting the error:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: conn in **/var/www/path/file.php** on line **24**

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in **/var/www/path/file.php** on line **24**

Line 24 is the line:

```
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `number1`, `number2`, `number3` FROM $database.tablename WHERE `id` = :id');
```

I don't know why this is happening, from what I have read I should be able to do this action within a function. I've not tried to access a DB within a custom function before, so help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you define database connection?

Comment: Isn't `$database` also undefined?

Comment: I can confirm that the connection is defined and working for all other DB connections/actions within the same file except this one specifically. There is a dbconf.php file which holds this data and is included at the start of the file.php. Apologies for not mentioning this earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access global variable here. To access them use it like

```
function doAddup01() {
     global $conn;
```